# How to add a custom UIButton to Interface Builder Object Library?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

Is that possible to add a subclassed UIButton to XCode 4.5 Interface Builder Object Library, but as Custom Object?

Here you can find the small sample project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioucpb6jn6nr0hs/blabla1.zip

Comment: While it is not ***impossible*** to modify IB to support custom controls (as the others state), it's certainly too much work compared to just writing a subclass and initializing it programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible to add new objects to the Interface Builder Object Library, but you can drag a regular UIButton out, and change the Custom Class property to you custom class name in the 3rd tab of the Identity Inspector. You wont see any of your customizations in the xib file though.

---

I took a look at your sample code. In the BlaButtonVC.m you have the method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

This doesn't get called when you're initing from the xib. You need to add the code in that method to

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
```

I tested it and it worked.

As an aside, I don't think BlaButtonVC is a good name, because it implies that your class is a view controller, when it is actually a view (unless VC stands for something else in your project).

Comment: Thank you for the verification. Also tried the approach you recommended, but it didn't work out, here you can find the other thread with this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786251/how-to-use-a-custom-uibutton-with-interface-builder

Comment: Tested with using initWithCoder method, and it's working now. Excellent! :) Beside your recommendation regarding the VC postfix is absolutely valid, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You used to able to do this in Xcode 3, but if I remember correctly it was a plugin thing (BWToolkit used to do it and was discontinued with Xcode 4). You can make a regular UIButton and change its class in the inspector window to the same effect though.