# How to use a custom UIButton with Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder, custom-controls

I have a subclass UIButton that loads a Nib:

```
@implementation BlaButtonVC

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *subViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlaButton" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:subViews[0]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And I can add this button to a view, like this:

```
// ViewController.m

BlaButtonVC *button = [[BlaButtonVC alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 44)];

button.titleXLabel.text = @"Nyuff";
button.descLabel.text = @"Kukk";

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

My problem is I don't know how to do it from Interface Bulder, how to use this UIButton subclass instead of the normal one.

Already changed Button Type to Custom, and Custom Class to BlaButtonVC, but it's not enough. It'll call BlaButtonVC initWithFrame, but button will not appear nor in Interface Builder, nor in Simulator.

What did I missed?

Here you can find the full sample: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioucpb6jn6nr0hs/blabla1.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When initialized from the `StoryBoard`, it calls the method `initWithCoder:` instead of `initWithFrame:`. Aside from that, everything is correct.

Comment: Yes, it calls the `-initWithCoder:`, but you should not override it. Instead you should override `-awakeFromNib`, because at that moment everything is set up. (Don't even think about calling these two by yourself.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with overriding both `initWithCoder:` and `awakeFromNib`. It depends on how he wants it to be set up.

Comment: In most (if not all) cases `-awakeFromNib` is better to override. See docs for [`-[NSObject(UINibLoadingAdditions) awakeFromNib]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder you can not add subviews to `UIButton`, so here are some ideas:

1. Do it in code.
2. Place the button below the labels and image, so it would receive touches and work as expected.
3. Use `UITableView` with cells (this looks like what you are trying to achieve).
4. Use custom `UIView` with `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @Julian Do you see the word _“not”_ in my answer? It’s 6th. Anyway, looking at the question and my answer after 3 years, they makes no sense to me.