# Adding a custom uibutton through interface builder

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder, xib

I've created a custom class, a child of `UIButton` with some custom features. Is it possible to place this custom button onto a view not with the code but using Interface Builder somehow, like we do it with standart `UIButton`, dragging it from the object library and dropping onto the view? Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a custom UIButton to Interface Builder Object Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782639/how-to-add-a-custom-uibutton-to-interface-builder-object-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In xib, select UIButton -> In Custom Class, select class as "CustomButton" name(Your custom class name).
Then declare your property,
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet CustomButton *yourButton;
connect this property to Files owner.
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, `@property` attribute for `IBOutlet` should be `weak`, not `strong`

Comment: It depends on whether the button is a top level object (it usually isn't so weak is OK)